# AngularJS - setting up config params dynamically for all the app envoirment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, config, parameters

Hi i'm trying setting up the app config params i need all around (global config params).

I tryed like this:

http://pastebin.com/PdQrzLT5

then

```
<html ng-controller="ConfigController">
```

but this won't work cause i need to refresh for exmaple the $location.$$path every time i refresh a page or everytime a route changes.

I would like to set a list of config params to make they global for using them into views and all around also in the app.js enteire file.

How do you usually do?

Comment: Don't you want to use the `$routeProvider` for this?

Comment: @ToddMotto why not :) if it's a good practice... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

- I use `$rootScope` for global configuration ( no need for another controller )
- You **should use** `$routeChangeStart` / `$routeChangeSuccess` to update global route configurations.
- use `$location.path()` instead of `$location.$$path`
- use `$location.url()` instead of `$location.$$url`

You can listen to `$routeChangeStart event` inside a run block like so:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location){
    var update =  function (){
      $rootScope.config = {
        appname: "Ouch" ,
        appurl: $location.url(),
        apppath: $location.path()
      }

    }  
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', update)
    update();
})
```

#### Is it a best practice?

- My approach is to use what makes my application simple and clear.
- If I have global objects which have to be bound all over the place inside my view, then `$rootScope` is the glue.
- If I only have to bound values to some elements I use `$route events` inside directives.

#### Example with directive

```
app.directive('routeConfig', function($rootScope, $location){   
    return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: "config-route.html",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){

            var update =  function (){
              $scope.config = {
                appname: "Ouch" ,
                appurl: $location.url(),
                apppath: $location.path()
              }

            }  

            $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', update)
            update();
        }
    }
});
```

**config-route.html:**

```
<h1>route:</h1>
<ul>
  <li> name: {{ config.appname}} </li>
  <li> url: {{ config.appurl}} </li>
  <li> path: {{ config.apppath}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i like a lot this way, but do you think it's a good practice?

Comment: can i then use these config params in all the envoirment?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services), like:

```
var cmnApp = angular.module('cmnApp',[]);
cmnApp.factory('UserService', function() {
  return {
      name : 'Some Name'
  };
});
```

and in some controller:

```
function someCtrl($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.name = UserService.name;
}
```

Comment: thank you man can you just tell me why is this better instead of using a configcontroller for example? i'm new on angular

Comment: its because services are singletons objects or functions that carry out specific tasks common to web apps.So, it generates a single object, or function, that represents the service to the rest of the application, and loads lazily meaning it is executed only when needed.